# Verification of Computation of Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $f = x^8-10x^4 + 1$. We want the Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$ 
The roots are $\pm \sqrt{ \pm \sqrt{5 \pm 2\sqrt6}}$.  I'm not sure about the splitting field,but I think that it would just be $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6})$, but I can't figure out if this would cover the root $\sqrt[4]{5-2\sqrt6}$.  
Then $|Gal_f{Q}| = [\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6}): \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6})][\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6}):\mathbb{Q}]$.  
 I claim that  $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6}):\mathbb{Q}] = 8$ because of the minimal polynomial $f = x^8-10x^4 + 1$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6})] = 2$ since the minimal polynomial x^2 + 1 is of degree 2.  This means that $Gal_f(\mathbb{Q})| = 2\times8=16$ so the Galois group is isomorphic to some subgroup of $S_8$ of order $16$

Is this correct? Could someone please help me figure out what group of order $16$ it would be isomorphic to?  Thanks

Comment: @Arthur Yes I fixed it!  Thank you

Comment: $i=\sqrt[4]{1}=\sqrt[4]{\left(5+2\sqrt{6}\right)\left(5-2\sqrt{6}\right)}$

Comment: @sharding4 Are you saying that I don't need to include $i$ in the extension?  Should the splitting field be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5 + 2 \sqrt6}, \sqrt[4]{5-2\sqrt6})$ or am I still wrong?

Comment: Actually I was thinking that you could get $\sqrt[4]{5-2\sqrt6}$ from something like $i/\sqrt[4]{5+2\sqrt6}$, so you were correct about the splitting field being $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6})$

Comment: @sharding4 Ok that's wonderful.  Thank you.  Do you have any idea if the rest of what I say is correct?

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: @sharding4 Could you please help me figure out which subgroup of order $16$ it is?  There are a few and I can never figure out which one it would be

Comment: Looks like a little brain freeze last night on $1/\sqrt[4]{5+2\sqrt{6}}=\sqrt[4]{5-2\sqrt{6}}$.  I believe (from Pari/GP) that the Galois Group may be $D_4\times C_2$.  I don't know a quick way to show that.  I'd suggest looking at your polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}], \Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$ or $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{6}]$ and using standard techniques to try to show that the Galois group of one of the resulting quartics is $D_4$.  I also found a few results searching for Galois Group order 16.

Comment: $x^8-10x^4+1=(x^4-5-2\sqrt{6})(x^4-5+2\sqrt{6})$, and the quartics have Galois group $D_4$ over $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{6}]$ (they're Kummer extensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the Galois group is non-abelian as complex conjugation will not commute with any automorphism that sends $\sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6} \to i\sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6}$.  Now $\sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6} = \sqrt{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}=\alpha$, say, so we see that the splitting field contains at least 7 quadratic subfields, $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{6}],\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}],\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}],\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{i}],\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-2}],\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}],\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-6}]$.  I believe that limits us to only $D_4\times C_2$ as having the required 7 seven normal subgroups of order 8 (using the subgroup structure for groups of order 16 that can be found [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_16)).

If the Galois group is the direct product, we should also be able to show that using the result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2068332/254075).  That is, we need to find 2 Galois subfields with intersection $\Bbb{Q}$ that generate the splitting field.  For $D_4\times C_2$ we'll need to find a dihedral and a quadratic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ contained in $\mathbb{Q}[i, \sqrt[4]{5 + 2\sqrt6}]=K$.

The dihedral extension we want will turn out to be the splitting field of $x^4-2x^2-2$, one root of which is $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{3}}$.  It's a tedious but not too difficult check that 
\begin{align}\frac{1}{4}\left(\alpha^7+\alpha^5-9\alpha^3-9\alpha\right)&= \frac{\alpha}{4}\left(\alpha^6+\alpha^4-9\alpha^2-9\right) \\
&= \frac{\alpha}{4}\left(11\sqrt{2} + 9\sqrt{3} +5 + 2\sqrt{6}-9\sqrt{2}-9\sqrt{3} -9\right) \\
&= \frac{\alpha}{4}\left(-4 + 2\sqrt{2}+ 2\sqrt{6} \right) = \frac{\alpha}{2}\left(-2 + \sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{6} \right) \\
&= \sqrt{\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\right)\left(3 - \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{6}\right) } \\
&= \sqrt{1+\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}
$1+\sqrt{3}$ satisfies $g(x)=x^4-2x^2-2$ which is Eisenstein at 2, so it's clear that $1+\sqrt{3}$ isn't a square in $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$.  Since $1-\sqrt{3}<0$ two of the roots of $g$ are complex and the degree of the splitting field, call it $F$, must then be 8.  Thus the Galois group must be $D_4$.  Now $F$ contains the quadratic subfields $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}],\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-2}]$ and $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-6}]$, but any of the other 4 quadratic subfields of $K$ along with $F$ will generate $K$, so $\Bbb{Q}[i]$, say.  Thus we get $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\Bbb{Q})\cong D_4\times C_2$ as desired.